# Horizontal scrolling doesn't work for ListBox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I tried to use this template for my listbox but when I use mouse wheel,  horizontal scrolling doesn't work and I don't know why!

ListBox Template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ListBoxControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <ScrollViewer Focusable="True" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Template="{DynamicResource ScrollViewerTargeting}" CanContentScroll="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

ScrollViewer Template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ScrollViewerTargeting" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
            <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Rectangle x:Name="Corner" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
                <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="True" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Template="{DynamicResource ComboBoxScrollBarControlTemplate}" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Margin="200,0,200,20" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="0" 
                    Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Grid.Row="1" 
                    Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" 
                    Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                    ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Template="{DynamicResource ScrollBarControlTemplate}" Focusable="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Scrollbar template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ScrollBarControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
            <Grid x:Name="Bg" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}}"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1E-05*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}}"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--<Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Visible" Background="#FF232323" Height="3" >-->
                <Border CornerRadius="1" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Visible"  Height="2" >
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="2,0"
                            SpreadMethod="Reflect" MappingMode="Absolute">
                            <!--<GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0" />-->
                            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.499" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF232323" Offset="0.5" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_LineLeftButton" Command="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Visibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                    <RepeatButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}"/>
                    </RepeatButton.Style>
                    <Path x:Name="ArrowLeft" Data="M3.18,7C3.18,7 5,7 5,7 5,7 1.81,3.5 1.81,3.5 1.81,3.5 5,0 5,0 5,0 3.18,0 3.18,0 3.18,0 0,3.5 0,3.5 0,3.5 3.18,7 3.18,7z" Fill="#FF606060" Margin="3" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                </RepeatButton>
                <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Visibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand">
                            <RepeatButton.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                                                <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </RepeatButton.Style>
                        </RepeatButton>
                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand">
                            <RepeatButton.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                                                <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </RepeatButton.Style>
                        </RepeatButton>
                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <Track.Thumb>
                        <Thumb>
                            <Thumb.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                                <!--<Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FF232323" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>-->
                                                <Border x:Name="rectangle" CornerRadius="3" Background="#FF232323" Height="7" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
                                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="rectangle" Value="#FF9d9d9d"/>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="rectangle" Value="#FF79cd00"/>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Thumb.Style>
                        </Thumb>
                    </Track.Thumb>
                </Track>
                <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_LineRightButton" Grid.Column="2" Command="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Visibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                    <RepeatButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}"/>
                    </RepeatButton.Style>
                    <Path x:Name="ArrowRight" Data="M1.81,7C1.81,7 0,7 0,7 0,7 3.18,3.5 3.18,3.5 3.18,3.5 0,0 0,0 0,0 1.81,0 1.81,0 1.81,0 5,3.5 5,3.5 5,3.5 1.81,7 1.81,7z" Fill="#FF606060" Margin="3" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                </RepeatButton>
            </Grid>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineRightButton}" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineRightButton}" Value="true"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowRight" Value="White"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineLeftButton}" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineLeftButton}" Value="true"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowLeft" Value="White"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineRightButton}" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineRightButton}" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowRight" Value="Black"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_LineLeftButton}" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_LineLeftButton}" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowLeft" Value="Black"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowLeft" Value="#FFBFBFBF"/>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ArrowRight" Value="#FFBFBFBF"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

where is the problem and how can I solve it?

[You can download an example from here](https://www.mediafire.com/?35gxn26w77zw0mh)

Comment: do you have enough columns or horizontal content to make the scroll happen ?

Comment: There is _way_ too much code in your example, and yet it fails to include enough code to be complete. Please simplify the code example, so that you have provided [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably demonstrates the problem.

Comment: ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" should not be on ItemsPresenter it should be set through the ListBox style.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here:

```
           <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ScrollViewer Focusable="True" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Template="{DynamicResource ScrollViewerTargeting}" CanContentScroll="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
```

try switching between the scrollviewer and the border's position so it looks like this:

```
           <ScrollViewer Focusable="True" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Template="{DynamicResource ScrollViewerTargeting}" CanContentScroll="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
                </Border>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have made an example and you can see how horizontal scrolling doesn't work. [You can download this example here](https://www.mediafire.com/?35gxn26w77zw0mh)

Comment: try opening ur project in blend.... then right click on LBGameList in ur objects and timeline window.... then choose "group into" and pick scrollviewer there. so it looks something like this http://prntscr.com/799wb2                                                                            oh and don't forget to set the scrollviewers horizontal bar to auto or visible.... it's default value is disabled I think.